# CSS select: how to count and select child of a specific class only?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

**Given the HTML where all items are at the same level such:**

```
<div class="h2">Title: Colors</div>
 <div class="pair">Hello world (1)</div>
 <div class="pair">Hello world (2)</div>
 <div class="pair">Hello world (3)</div>
 <div class="pair">Hello world (4)</div>
 <div class="pair">Hello world (5)</div>
 <div class="pair">Hello world (6)</div>

<div class="h2">Title: Units</div>
 <div class="pair">Hello world (1)</div>
 <div class="pair">Hello world (2)</div>
 <div class="pair">Hello world (3)</div>
 <div class="pair">Hello world (4)</div>
 <div class="pair">Hello world (5)</div>
 <div class="pair">Hello world (6)</div>
```

**How do I select the n+3 and n+4 .pair elements starting from the previous .h2 element ?**

So the 1&2 are white, 3&4 are pink, 5&6 are white, etc.

I tried `.pair:nth-child(4n+3), .pair:nth-child(4n+4) { background: #FFAAAA; }` but it counts the child of the body where the `h2` are also children and thus breaks my balance.

http://jsfiddle.net/zPYcy/2/

---

**Edit:** no pure CSS selector was found to select adjacent items following a pattern such as .class (n+3). Alternatively, **an infinite series of CSS selectors** such `div + .class + .class + .class ...`; **wrapping** in a div together with `:nth-child(n+3)` or `:nth-of-type(n+3)`; or **JS** is needed. You know another hack ? Sharing welcome !

Comment: Try using `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of boredom and curiosity I've written a function to do this. In the case that you are stuck with the html as is and you have extended rows like this, my plugin could be useful to you.

Copy the function from my jsFiddle and use like so:

```
var pair1 = findCousin('h2', 'pair', '4n+2');
var pair2 = findCousin('h2', 'pair', '4n+3');
var s = pair1.add(pair2);
```

You can change `h2` and `pair` two different class names, or use different patterns as long as it has `#n` in it, and optionally `+#` just like the css nth child selector. Adding `false` as a fourth argument...

```
findCousin('list-title', 'list-item', '3n', false);
```

...will select everything after the first `list-title` in the given pattern, rather than after *each* `list-item`.... if that makes any sense.

I believe sh0ber has written a more practical solution, but this has been fun to make and I might as well share.

http://jsfiddle.net/REU33/6/

Comment: Downvote with no comment? I'm curious if I overshot here or if theres an easier js/jQuery solution here I've missed?

Comment: I thought surely one of these answers was right for you, perhaps you can make your question more clear with an edit? I don't get what you mean by "the HTML class include class that we already knows." Happy to try to help if you do

Comment: (oups, my previous comment now deleted answered to the wrong post.)

Comment: I was first reluctant to accept a JS solution, but it really seems there is no CSS selector satisfying my need. Your JS doing perfectly the job, your JS is the best ! See @Jamil fiddle!

Comment: Note: your fiddle is awesome :)

Answer (score 5):

This is a solution combining  **sibling** , **nth-child** and **nth-last-child** selector.

Each of your divs with class h2 should also use an extra class that I will call "colors" and "units"
like so:

```
<div class="h2 colors">Title: Colors</div>
...
<div class="h2 units">Title: Colors</div>
...
```

We apply for all children that presents a preceding sibling with classes **h2** and **colors** the following rule which will paint the pink divs

```
.h2.colors ~ .pair:nth-child(4n+4), .h2.colors ~ .pair:nth-child(4n+5) { 
    background: #FFAAAA; 
}
```

Of course this will also paint those divs below the div of classes **h2** and **units**. We don`t want that to happen.
So now we apply the following two rules, selecting in inverse order up to h2 units.

```
.h2.units ~ .pair:nth-last-child(4n+3), .h2.units ~ .pair:nth-last-child(4n+4) { 
    background: #FFAAAA; 
}
```

Be aware that now we must also apply the white background to fix the extra divs painted by our first rule
So...

```
 .h2.units ~ .pair:nth-last-child(4n+1), .h2.units ~ .pair:nth-last-child(4n+2) { 
        background: #ffffff; 
    }
```

Only thing to take care is the odd or even number of divs in the last group when we are using the nth-last-child selector.

And there you are!

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/HE2he/) to play with

Comment: +1 to this, simple, clean and expandable. I didn't even think this was possible with css only

Comment: This answer imply to have classes that we already knows when we write down the CSS, not yet the hack I'am looking for. I +1ed your answer since witty.

Comment: I am looking for a CSS selector like `.h2 + .pair + .pair + .pair + .pair` but in a scalable way `.h2 + .pair(4n)` which just doesn't seems to exist.

Answer (score 3):

If we want *only* the 3rd and 4th .pair after each `.h2`, then this will work:

```
.h2 + .pair + .pair + .pair,
.h2 + .pair + .pair + .pair + .pair { background: #FFAAAA; }
```

If we want to continue to alternate by two even in a longer list, we will need another solution.

---

**EDIT**: Since we do want a scalable solution, if we can change the markup slightly by wrapping each block of `.pair` items with another class:

```
<div class="h2 colors">Title: Colors</div>
<div class="pairList">
    <div class="pair">Hello world</div>
    <div class="pair">Hello world</div>
    <div class="pair">Hello world</div>
    <div class="pair">Hello world</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Then we can write a rule that will scale for any amount of items like:

```
.pairList .pair:nth-of-type(4n+3), 
.pairList .pair:nth-of-type(4n+4) { 
    background: #FFAAAA; 
}
```

[Here is a FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/fU8gb/)

Comment: 5&6 are white, etc. It's mean that 7&8 should be pink. Your code don't do it so your answer is incorect.

Comment: The question was:  "How to select the n+3 and n+4 .pair elements starting from the previous .h2 element ?"  7&8 are really 1&2 starting from the next .h2 element. We'll have to wait to see what the OP wants. You may want to read the site TOS, this is not exactly grounds for a downvote :)

Comment: Ok I cancel downvote but this `pair:nth-child(4n+3)` and this `1&2 are white, 3&4 are pink, 5&6 are white, etc.` suggest me that I have right :)

Comment: I agree that it could be either way. Hopefully the OP will tell us.

Comment: Shober idea is interesting and should get some +1. But indeed, I look for a more scalable solution above applying style (bg:pink) to 3-4, 7-8, 11-12 etc.

Comment: Your code works but it's not the answer. I generate the HTML code based on a Json, so I get a list of div elements all direct child of body. I precisely wonder if there is a way to get the needed elements **WITHOUT** changing the markup structure. I look for a solution upon <div>a</div> <div>b</div> <div>c</div>, without wrapping up such **<div>** <div>a</div> <div>b</div> <div>c</div> **</div>**.

Comment: That's why I said "*if* we can change" ;)

Comment: yes... I will likely have to move my code to your 2nd alternative (wrapping). And thanks for these tricks :D

Comment: I eventually used Jamil solution since both scalable and not changing the html structure.